# работа с mysql в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Добрый день! Как организовать класс взаимодействующий с базой данных, который должен считывать несколько связанных между собой таблиц (образующих один объект с данными) из базы данных MySQL и отображать соответствующие таблицы с возможностью редактирования.

Мои предположения - нужно использовать MVC где вышеупомянутый класс будет являться моделью.

Какие контейнеры используются для хранения в памяти таблиц из БД. Какие наиболее эффективнее, и для чего используется модель для работы с базой данных в Qt. Объясните новичку как должно взаимодействовать приложение с БД, при больших объемах данных, при это необходимо чтение/запись и еще много чего. И если кто то хочет помочь(кто достаточное знает qt) с написание приложения - можно обсудить по почте.

Answer (score 2):

В Qt есть специальные библиотеки, позволяющие осуществлять SQL запросы с помощью ODBC драйверов, и результаты запроса хранятся в специальном объекте. Можно, конечно, распарсить таблицы в собственные объекты, но целесообразно ли это?

В [данной статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/51650/) неплохо описаны основы работы с SQL в Qt.

Comment: Но только в этом примере одна таблица, а у меня - несколько и связанных друг с другом.

Comment: Используйте запросы для связанных таблиц точно так же, как и обычные запросы

Comment: А можете пример мне расписать? Просто вообще не понятно.

Comment: Например SELECT table1.field1, table2.field2 FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.fieldx = table2.fieldy

Comment: Для каждой таблицы свой QSqlTableModel?

Comment: Желательно, так как данный класс предназначен для представления поведения одной таблицы для виджета, отображающего таблицы, и имея свою модель для каждой таблицы, для того, чтоб отобразить другую таблицу в виджете вам будет достаточно сменить модель на ходу.

Comment: Но можно же не использовать эту модель, так? Тогда что использовать?

Comment: Тогда самому распарсить таблицы и выводить их в графический интерфейс как нужно.

Comment: А можно пример??

Comment: Например получили из запроса 10 чисел, и вывели их в интерфейс методом setText в текстовые поля

Comment: Ну а если нужно работать с несколькими таблицами, которые отображаем в TableView то нужен класс хранящий данные? Если данные нужно именно подгрузить и работать с ними

Comment: Все эти вопросы следует продумать вам, продумать архитектуру, как оно все работать. На каждый подобный вопрос нет единственно правильного ответа, можно комбинировать и придумывать разные решения, подходящие именно вам.